# Why dial up modem always dial up again and again automaticly

Tags: dial-up

please anyone help me this out, my dial up modem when I'm downloding file it's Always automatic dial to ISP over and over again, so my downloading stop and start over again, this make me terrible, so is there any tools or something that make not to dial up again but I can continoue downloading, thanks anyone

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which you are using but many OS's do not support resuming of downloads from interrupted connections with their built in web browsers.

What you need to do is download a "Download manager". Wikipedia has [a large list of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers), just find one for your OS that has a `Yes` "Resuming" column in the [features section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers#Features). What this will do is when your connection is lost and your dial up re-dials the download will just continue from where it was disconnected instead of restarting from the beginning.